# Qtablewidget does not scroll smoothly

Tags: python, scroll, qtablewidget

**Problem:** I have QTableWidget cells populated with text (10 columns). I found out that no matter how much rows I have (10 or 100000) scrolling over rows with heigth ~ over 3000 is very slow and not smooth enough (I've used `table.verticalHeader().sectionSize(i)` to find out heigth of every row).

**What I've tried to do:** So I've tried to set height of those rows using `table.setRowHeight(i,3000)`, but still when I scroll over those rows I get delay of 1-5 secunds. Also in that case I need to manualy resize height of row in order to see all text in that row (because it was cuted), and that is slow too.

**Questions:** I need to do `table.resizeRowsToContent()` for all smaller rows, so I think solution would be to set limit for height of every row in table. There is setMinimumSectionSize() method but I can't find any for max size, so how can I do it? Is it possible to have scrollbars inside every cell where height is >3000 so I can scroll through text inside that cell? Maybe that will speed up scrolling throug table?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I've solved it:
While populating table cells with text, if my text have over 1000 lines (`text.count("\n")`) I put it in `QTextEdit()` and then set it with `setCellWidget`. Reason I didn't put them all in `QTextEdit()`s is that Windows can show limited number of GUI elements (<20000) and, as I said, I have 10 columns x up to 100000 rows

Comment: Pretty interesting hack there! :)

Comment: gave me a headache. I've spent several days searching for a solution but end up with this hack. I don't know better :)

Comment: Do you know why QTableWidget don't smooth scroll? It's not scrolling using our mouse scroll distance/speed. It looks like it scroll in one unit of row. It'd be better if it scroll like browser window.. I hope I explain that clearly :)

Comment: what you need is to set: `yourTableWidget.setVerticalScrollMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.ScrollPerPixel)`

Comment: HI @Aleksandar, I already ask it in my other thread, and yes, that is the correct answer